# Why is Stack Overflow's popularity decreasing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, answers, voting

I wrote the following query on data.stackexchange.com. It returned some astonishing results.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273685/stackoverflow-average-votes-vs-viewed-count

**Observations**

1. Newer questions are getting fewer and fewer visits.
2. Average votes per questions are decreasing.
3. Fewer answers are getting posted. Highest number of answers between 2013 to 2017.

**My best guesses**

1. Most people are asking generic questions which have already been answered before. Hence newer questions are less likely to turn up in results.
2. *People are more likely to upvote an answer that already has higher number of upvotes.*
3. People are frugal while casting their votes for new answers.

**Dangers**

1. This is creating an unfavourable environment for such an important platform. Since newer posts are not getting enough visits/votes, new programmers are not getting enough encouragement to write good answers.
2. Many old veterans are writing fewer posts. There are exceptions, especially a Good Samaritan like Jon Skeet. But even his daily reputation points gain has halved.
3. Newer technologies are less likely to have patrons who passionately and selflessly write answers.

*What steps should be taken to encourage young programmers to be more forthcoming in helping other?*

Comment: 1, 2 & 3 newer questions have had less time to accumulate views, votes and answers.

Comment: I'm going to send this over to MSO, because it's asking about that site only.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: But now [it is *'Post Closed as "Not suitable for this site"'*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/400173/revisions) (and locked with the terrible misspelling).

Comment: They have removed features that were there for a reason and made user interface more and more ugly.

Comment: I think the policies have become more and more strict, people have become more fed up. After the Monica issue especially, a lot of experienced people left. It's quicker to get an answer on github issues now, compared to SO.